# Import large amounts of data, but do a .find() for each element

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loops, mongoose

I have a collection of customers of 60.000 items. I need to import a list of people, of 50.000. But for each person, I need to find the ID of the customer and add that to the object that is being inserted.

How should this be done most efficently?

```
export default async ({ file, user, database }: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const csv = file.buffer.toString("utf8");

    let lines = await CSV({
      delimiter: "auto" // delimiter used for separating columns.
    }).fromString(csv);

    let count = {
      noCustomer: 0,
      fails: 0
    };

    let data: any = [];
    await Promise.all(
      lines.map(async (item, index) => {
        try {

          // Find customer
          const customer = await database
            .model("Customer")
            .findOne({
              $or: [
                { "custom.pipeID": item["Organisasjon - ID"] },
                { name: item["Person - Organisasjon"] }
              ]
            })
            .select("_id")
            .lean();

          // If found a customer
          if (!isNil(customer?._id)) {
            return data.push({
              name: item["Person - Navn"],
              email: item["Person - Email"],
              phone: item["Person - Telefon"],
              customer: customer._id,
              updatedAt: item["Person - Oppdater tid"],
              createdAt: item["Person - Person opprettet"],
              creator: users[item["Person - Eier"]] || "5e4bca71a31da7262c3707c5"
            });
          } 
          else {
            return count.noCustomer++;
          }
        } catch (err) {
          count.fails++;
          return;
        }
      })
    );

    const people = await database.model("Person").insertMany(data)

    res.send("Thanks!")

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    throw err;
  }
};
```

My code just never sends an response If I use this as a Express request.

Comment: your code is incomplete. What happens after you Promise.all()? do you catch errors and send them to the client? Btw; you are not returning any promise to your Promise.all

Comment: updated my code

Comment: maybe also `res.send()` something in your catch statement or look at your log? check if you are actually getting a file and that `lines` actually have a length.